# How to set different styles for different rows in html table created from php array?

Tags: php

I'm struggling with creating a html table from php array, while applying different css classes on different rows according to the array.

I have this code in *data.php*:

```
<?php
$data = array(
  array('Title 1'=>'text11', 'Title 2'=>'text12'),
  array('Title 1'=>'text21', 'Title 2'=>'text22'),
  array('Title 1'=>'text31', 'Title 2'=>'text32'),
  array('Title 1'=>'text41', 'Title 2'=>'text42', 'special'=>'style1'),
  array('Title 1'=>'text51', 'Title 2'=>'text52', 'special'=>'style2'),
  );
?>
```

I want to create a html table from this array, and if the array contains 'special'=>'style', it would set that style to that particular row. This is my code so far:

```
<?php include('data.php'); ?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title 1</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($data as $key=>$row):
        if ($row == 'class1') {
          $class='class="style1"';
          } elseif ($row == 'class1') {
            $class='class="style2"';
          } else {
            $class='';
          }?>
    <tr <?php echo $class ?>>
      <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the desired output:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title 1</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>text11</td><td>text12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text21</td><td>text22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text31</td><td>text32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="style1">
      <td>text41</td><td>text42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="style2">
      <td>text51</td><td>text52</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: for a start $row is an array as $data  is multidimensional, there is nothing inside the array with 'class1' ..

Comment: `if ($row['special'] == 'class1') {` Although the contents of `special` appears to be inverted from your code example, which seems to indicate this would work with your existing array: `if ($row['special'] == 'style1') { $class = 'class1';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key=>$row):
```

You're forgetting that you're looping over a multidimensional array (i.e. an array of arrays) so that `$row` is an array here. On the next line:

```
if ($row == 'class1')
```

You're looking for a comparison between a string and `$row` which is an array. This will never work! As Daniel points out in his answer, you need to look at the contents of the array.

Don't forget you'll need to remove the `special` element from the array before displaying it. Personally, I'd condense the code a bit, though mixing PHP and HTML like this is never a good idea.

```
<?php include('data.php'); ?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title 1</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($data as $row): $class = $row["special"] ?? ""; unset($row["special"]);?>
    <tr class="<?=$class?>">
      <td><?=implode("</td><td>", $row)?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation, yeah, I totally forgot that $row is also an array. And yes, mixing php and html like that is not perfect, but I don't like redundant class="" in every row.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do the job.

The result is as you desire, see: [Online PHP shell](https://3v4l.org/fqJbk)

```
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title 1</th>
          <th>Title 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($data as $key=>$row):
            if (isset($row["special"])) {
              $class = " class='" . $row["special"]. "'";    
              unset($row["special"]);
              } else {
                $class='';
              }?>
        <tr<?php echo $class ?>>
          <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: A helpful answer should explain what the problem is, rather than just throwing some code out. Ideally the person asking the question will come away having learned something more than "SO will fix my code for me!"

Comment: Thank you for answering, it's nice and easy solution, although @miken32 answer was more explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood everything but you can try this

```php
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $row):
    $class = '';
    if(isset($row['special'])){
        $class = 'class="'.$row['special'].'"';
        unset($row['special']);
    }
 ?>
<tr <?php echo $class ?>>
    <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: A helpful answer should explain what the problem is, rather than just throwing some code out. Ideally the person asking the question will come away having learned something more than "SO will fix my code for me!"

Comment: yes but sometimes some action is better that a long speech

Comment: Thank you for answering, it's nice and easy solution, although @miken32 answer was more explanatory.